Update SearchBar's ListTile in flet
I have a list whose items I want to filter according to what the user types in the search bar. Let's say the user types "o" in the search bar. In this case I would like to update the ListTile to only show fruits that have the substring "o" in their names. My code is:
import flet as ft

fruits_list = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape", "strawberry", "watermelon", "kiwi", "pineapple", "mango", "pear"]

list_to_show = fruits_list


def main(page):
    global list_to_show

    def handle_change(e):
        global list_to_show
        list_to_show = [i for i in fruits_list if e.data in i]

    anchor = ft.SearchBar(
        view_elevation=4,
        divider_color=ft.colors.BLUE,
        bar_hint_text="Search for fruits...",
        view_hint_text="Suggestions...",
        on_change=handle_change,
        controls=[
            ft.ListTile(title=ft.Text(f"{i}"), data=i)
            for i in list_to_show
        ],
    )

    page.add(
        ft.Row([
            anchor
        ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
        )
    )


ft.app(target=main, view=ft.AppView.WEB_BROWSER)

What I get
The problem is: The ListTile only shows the first value of list_to_show. I tried the following but it didn't work:
def handle_change(e):
    global list_to_show
    list_to_show = [i for i in fruits_list if e.data in i]

    anchor.controls.clear()
  
    for item in list_to_show:
        anchor.controls.append(ft.ListTile(title=ft.Text(f"{item}"), on_click=close_anchor, data=item))
    
    anchor.update()


problem is flet search bar doesn't support to change controls when search bar clicked. you need to use different container to show your result instead of search bar controls.

you can get solution on this github issue  https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/issues/2874

Apparently, you need to create a list view variable and add it to the anchor controls:
import flet as ft

def main(page):

    fruits_list = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape", "strawberry", "watermelon", "kiwi", "pineapple", "mango", "pear"]

    def open_anchor(e):
        anchor.open_view()

    def close_anchor(e):
        anchor.close_view(e.control.data)

    def handle_change(e):
        list_to_show = [fruit for fruit in fruits_list if e.data.lower() in fruit]
        lv.controls.clear()
        for i in list_to_show:
            lv.controls.append(ft.ListTile(title=ft.Text(f"{i}"), on_click=close_anchor, data=i))
        anchor.update()

    lv = ft.ListView()
    anchor = ft.SearchBar(
    view_elevation=4,
    divider_color=ft.colors.BLUE,
    bar_hint_text="Search for fruits...",
    view_hint_text="Suggestions...",
    on_change=handle_change,
    on_tap=open_anchor,
    controls=[
        lv
    ],
    )

    page.add(
        ft.Row([
            anchor
        ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
        )
    )

ft.app(main)

Credit to bhushanrathod32 who solved this problem in this GitHub post
